# How is possible implementing MVVM in Swift with an environment object containing the data and differents view/view models?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm trying to implement my app architecture loading in the app struct an object containing the data to be shared in all the views of the app through an environment object:

```
@main
struct SMT_testingApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var dataManager = DataManager()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(dataManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Datamanager class publishing the var containing the data:

```
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var SMTItemList: [SMTItem] = [SMTItem(id: UUID(), itemDesc: "", itemCreaDate: Date(), itemUpdDate: Date(), itemTags: [], linkedItemsUID: [])]
    
    var urlFile: URL {
        getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("/SMT.json")
    }
    
    init() { loadData() }
    
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    func loadData() {
//...
```

After here the View that contain the instance of his view model:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.dataManager.SMTItemList) { item in
            SMTItemView(item: item)
               }
    }
}

struct SMTItemView: View {
    var item : SMTItem
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item desc: \(item.itemDesc)")
    }
    
}
```

And finally, the view model that contains the environment object with the data.

```
extension ContentView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
        @EnvironmentObject var dataManager: DataManager
    }
}
```

Now, the code is built correctly but at runtime I obtain this error in the content View:

[image: Error in the Content View]

What I'm doing wrong? Is correct implementing an architecture that way (one enviroment object with the data and many views/view models) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EnvironmentObject must be in view scope, not view model class. Like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var dataManager: DataManager    // << here !!

    var body: some View {
        List(dataManager.SMTItemList) { item in
            SMTItemView(item: item)
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Asperi, but that way the ContentView interacts directly with the dataManager object and not through the ContentViewModel. My objective was having one instance of a class that load the data and share it across the apps and then several views each one with his view model. It seems that way that the view model is completely not useful. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: EnvironmentObject/StateObject/ObservedObject are in-view observer wrappers for ObservableObject, so all of them view-model layer. Your dataManager in in-head concept, if you don't want it to be view model then don't do that, move out, and inject into ViewModel which, then, make EnvironmentObject or StateObject, whatever. All that is just concepts, how join those chains is up to you.

Comment: Mmm. The problem is the "up to you" I fear... :) and that these concepts are quite hard (for me at least). My objective is to do a note-taking app loading data from a JSON file in one unique instance and then decoupling as much as possible this object from the views using views/views models. Which is the right architecture in your opinion?